# Como capturar o data-tooltip usando selenium no Python

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Olá, é o seguinte o meu problema: Estou fazendo um web scraping na seguinte URL > https://www.maze.com.br/produto/tenis-nike-air-jordan-ma2-ultramarine-branco/4749595.
Acabei me deparando com um leve problema, na hora de selecionar o tamanho do produto (39.5; 40; 41; etc) eu simplesmente pensei num input no qual o usuário digita o tamanho do tênis:

```
tamanho = input('Tamanho do tênis? ')
```

Após isso eu iria fazer um `find_elements_by_class_name` e ver qual das classes possuem o valor da variável `tamanho`.
Acontece que isto não deu certo... 
Por algum motivo eu estou recebendo um array vazio `[]`. Após o erro pensei em pegar o valor que está em `data-tooltip` e comparar se o valor bate com a da variável inicial `tamanho`, ai que está o ponto todo! Eu não sei como eu posso pegar o valor descrito em `data-tooltip` para fazer a comparação de valores. Eu já pesquisei sobre o assunto e acabei por não encontrar nada e por isso estou aqui fazendo está pergunta.
Se também você souber qualquer outro método para eu conseguir selecionar o tamanho do tênis estou a ouvidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sou novo no python, mas pelo que entendi é mais ou menos isso a sua ideia ? Qualquer duvida com o código só perguntar, eu deixei um while no código para que você possa testar ele passando pelos tamanhos digitados no input

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.maze.com.br/produto/tenis-nike-air-jordan-ma2-ultramarine-branco/4749595'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', options=options)

try:
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(2)
    xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="references"]').find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//button[@class="ui basic button"]')
    tamanhos = [tamanho.text for tamanho in xpath if tamanho.text != '']
    print(f"Os tamanhos disponíveis são: {tamanhos} ")
    print(len(tamanhos))
    while True:
        escolha = input("Escolha o tamanho que deseja: ")
        if escolha not in tamanhos:
            print("O tamanho não existe na lista")
        else:
            opcao = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="references"]').find_element_by_xpath(
                f'//button[@data-tooltip="{escolha}"]')
            opcao.click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    driver.close()
```